# Is it possible to detect HTML form submit cancelation

Tags: html

We have plan-old-HTML-form with submit button.
We use onSubmit event to show some animation and disable the form to let the user know something is going on.

The problem is we want to be able to detect the user cancel the submit, either by pressing escape of clicking the cancel button or any other way each browser allow to do so.

Is it possible to detect HTML form submit canceled event?

P.S
When I wrote this question I submit this form and quickly press Esc which cancel the submit but leave the button disabled, so I guess it is not that easy :)

Comment: Detect the keypress and then cancel animation. Pretty simple.

Comment: if you're posting the form with ajax i think you can listen to the error event handler

Comment: Detecting keypress does not account for user cancel the submit with X button near the address bar so it only solve half of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I really dont see the possiblity of stopping using simple html, but you can use jquery ajax .please refer http://www.tutorialsbook.com/jquery/jquerydetails/jquery_ajax

Comment: Thank you. I understand how this can work but as you say it does not use plain-old-html so it's not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to detect a user cancelling normal page navigation. The only way I know to handle this is to set a timeout that will enable fields after a period of time. This has obvious flaws, but it might be as good as you can get.

Determining the right timeout will have to take into account the kind of latency you expect from your system, because it will re-enable your submit button if your request handler is taking too long.

I'm happy to be wrong on this, however.